# Determine Device Password and Encryption state on BB10 (ndk)

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-ndk

Is there an API that allows one to determine whether Device Password and (memory) Encryption are turned on by the user?

I'm using the C++/qml Stack at API Level 10.2

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need that?

Comment: To be able to recommend turning it on, since my application contains sensitive data (but only if its not already turned on).